# fullcalendar axis missing when modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I have issue with fullcalendar where when I modify the axis it disappears. here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        minTime: "09:15:00",
        maxTime: "18:15:00",
        slotDuration: "00:60:01",
    });

});
```

Which displays 
[this calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvNNd.png)

But I have used the exact same code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9mt92et/85/) and it does display the axis!!

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone else with this issue**

This is a known bug https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2786

There is a "ugly" workaround available provided on the issue.